# Ram memory issue on Magento 2.3.4 website

Tags: magento2, server-setup, optimization, memory

I have a Magento 2.3.4 website on my server in Production mode.

When I check memory usage with "top" command, I got a very high memory usage like this:

[image]

There are so many php-fpm processes

Can I kill php-fpm processes or do something in this situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading correctly you only have 8GiB of memory. If your Magento instance gets a decent amount of traffic and/or you're not serving your static files (css and js) from a CDN, Magento 2 will eat up your memory pretty quickly.

If you just want to ensure you're only spawning php-fpm workers as needed you can edit your php-fpm pool configuration file `www.conf`. The location of this file depends on the Linux distro you're using, for instance on Ubuntu Server this file is located at `/etc/php/<php version>/pool.d/www.conf`. Once you find the file open it and edit the following configuration options.

**NOTE: These options are already present in the file so you'll need to find them and update the value, don't just paste this into the file**

```
pm=dynamic
pm.max_children=20
pm.start_servers=10
pm.min_spare_servers=5
pm.max_spare_servers=15
```

Note the values for `pm.max_children`, `pm.start_servers`, `pm.min_spare_servers`, and `pm.max_spare_servers` will more than likely need to be tweaks to your needs, and the values I provided are on the low side.

Now you just need to restart your php-fpm process for the changes to take effect.

When `pm` is set to `dynamic` the php-fpm master process will spawn php-fpm workers as needed based on the values set above. When `pm` is set to `static` the php-fpm master process will always spawn the the maximum number of workers allowed based on the value of `pm.max_children`